# Designing a generic C++1z class

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime, template, c++17

I'm designing a generic interface for a MessageEntry class for a .h file.

I'm looking for guidance on form and terminology (would I call this an interface/template/generic class?):

```
#ifndef cppmq_message_types_h
#define cppmq_message_types_h

template <class T>
struct MessageEntry {
 public:
  MessageEntry<T>() {}
  MessageEntry<T>(T data) : data(data) {
    creation_time =
        std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
  }
  time_t CreationTime() { return creation_time; }

 private:
  T data;
  time_t creation_time;
};

#endif`
```

Comment: Questions containing **broken code** or asking for advice about code not yet written are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Please explain, and edit the title accordingly — see [ask].

Comment: I have restored your original (broken) code. Please see [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this code, starting from the fact that it is syntactically invalid. Getting past that, you have no access to your `data`, which makes it somewhat pointless, and the only way to construct a `MessageEntry` is to preconstruct a `T`, then copy it into the `MessageEntry` constructor, then copy it again into `data`. That can be unnecessarily expensive, and then you're not actually timestamping when you constructed the original object - you're timestamping two copies later.

You definitely want to be able to support *in-place* construction and you definitely want easy access to the data. Fortunately, you can solve both problems in one go with just simple inheritance:

```
template <typename T, typename Clock=std::chrono::system_clock>
struct MessageEntry : T
{
    using T::T;
    decltype(Clock::now()) creation_time = Clock::now();
};
```

That's... it. I added a second template argument in case your users want a different clock (e.g. `std::chrono::steady_clock`). I intentionally left `creation_time` non-`const` so as to make the class copyable. If you don't need this to be copyable, then I would write it as:

```
template <typename T, typename Clock=std::chrono::system_clock>
struct MessageEntry : T
{
    using T::T;
    const decltype(Clock::now()) creation_time = Clock::now();

    MessageEntry(MessageEntry const& ) = delete;
    MessageEntry& operator=(MessageEntry const& ) = delete;
};
```

It might be worth renaming the class to something that adds clarity to its intent. Perhaps `WithCreationTime`.

Lastly, I would prefer `#pragma once` just to be able to write less code for include guards, and you are missing your `#include` for `<chrono>`.

Full solution:

```
#pragma once

#include <chrono>

template <typename T,
          typename Clock = std::chrono::system_clock>
struct WithCreationTime : T
{
    using T::T;
    decltype(Clock::now()) creation_time = Clock::now();
};
```

Example usage:

```
WithCreationTime<std::vector<int>> v{1, 2, 3, 4};
std::cout << v.size() << '\n'; // 4
std::cout << v.creation_time << '\n'; // whatever now() is
```

Comment: Usually I don't like to inherit from the template argument, since it kind of mix horizontal and vertical design. Of course, there are exceptions (CRTP being the most famous); in this case the design is fine, since the added feature of the derived class/struct is universal and orthogonal to the template argument. The alternative would be to store a T member, and use variadic template in the constructor (something similar to what emplace does), but the design may be heavier (though someone may prefer it).